# mysqli_real_escape_string in function, not working?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I made a function exactley after how our teacher made in an online lecture. But its not working, the error message said first that there vas a varible missing. So i checked it up and on w3schools they say that you need the connection as varibale and the string. So I added the connection, but then i got an error that said that the varible vas undefined. I tried putting the function in different places in the php-document but i dont know how to work this one out, plz help?

My code (i deleted my passwords):

```
<?php

// A function to help prevent SQL Injection.
function preparePostData($value)
{
// Removes slashes (/) if the server automaticlly adds them.
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$value = stripslashes($value);
}

/* Adds quote marks if the value is not numeric or a numeric string. 
mysqli_real_escape_string adds slashes (/) if there is any character thats not allowed 
and then the text string will not be processed in MySQL. */
if(!is_numeric($value)){
$value = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $value) . "'";
}

return $value;
}

// If the submit button is set do this..
if(isset($_POST['saveNews'])){

// Connection to db
$dbConn = mysqli_connect("localhost","sabe0011","password","sabe0011");

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($dbConn)){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// SQL question
$insertSQL = "INSERT INTO News (NewsId, Headline, News, Date) VALUES ('NULL',".preparePostData($_POST['newsHeader']).",".preparePostData($_POST['news']).",".preparePostData($_POST['newsDate']).");";

if(mysqli_query($dbConn, $insertSQL)){
echo "Nyheter har sparats";
}

else{
echo "Följande fel uppstod " . mysqli_error() . ".";
}
}

// Connection to db
$dbConn = mysqli_connect("localhost","sabe0011","password","sabe0011");

$dbConn->set_charset("utf8");

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($dbConn)){
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$newsSQL = mysqli_query($dbConn,"SELECT * FROM News ORDER BY Date;");

echo "<div>";

if(mysqli_num_rows($newsSQL) > 0)
{   
while($rowNews = mysqli_fetch_array($newsSQL)){
echo '<h2>' . $rowNews["Headline"] . '</h2>' . '<time>' . $rowNews["Date"] . '</time>' . '<p>' . $rowNews["News"] . '</p>';
}
}

else{
echo "Inga nyheter hittades";
}

echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: If you use [SQL data placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) you would not need to do any of this. Wrapper functions like `preparePostData` are a terrible idea, they can hide implementation problems, and they only work if they're used consistently. A single mistake can be enough to ruin your application. Also, the best way to handle "magic quotes" is to turn them off, they should never be on in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you connect at the top of your script you'll need to somehow pass it your function. You have two options.  Either make it a parameter in you function. `function reparePostData($value,$dbconn);` Or you can declare your connection a global variable inside the function, and allow the function to access this variable inside the function `global $dbconn;`.

Comment: The global part worked well, but the other didint work at all doh =/. But now the problem is fixed, thank you! Know i need to fix that my fantastic swedish letters will get to the database and stay like that.. that dosent work know ^^

Comment: To use it as a parameter for the function you'd have to make sure to pass it to the function as a parameter when you call it. So where you call the function will also need to access the $dbconn.

Answer (score -2):

You are using this function wrong way.

mysqli_real_escape_string **has nothing to do with POST data**. Only magic quotes do.

So, you have to split this function into two:

1. One which [cleans your POST data from magic quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php#example-344).
2. One which produces a correct string literal

   ```
   function prepareSQLliteral($value)
   {
     if(!is_numeric($value)){
       global $dbConn;
       $value = "'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $value) . "'";
     }
     return $value;
   }
   ```

However, using manual formatting is not the way to go.
the same processing have to be done not on the global variable but on the very value that is going into query. And only prepared statements can do that.

But because mysqli prepared statements are quite unusable, you have to use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) instead.

Comment: Ok, but if i lose the first part the slashes wont be stripted if the server automaticley puts them infront of "bad" characters?

Comment: Having wrapper functions like this is a terrible idea. Using a global variable is even more terrifying.

Comment: I tried it and it workes well! But there was no problem keeping both in the same function, thank you very much!

Comment: Ah ok.. Well i dont know PDO jet, I heard that you could use it, I hope the techers are teaching us this just to tell us later then that we should use PDO, but right know this assaignment have to be in tomorrow, so this has to work for the moment. Thanks for helping, and thanks for pointing out that theres better ways to do it!